# How do we extract json first array element in postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql

Tablename:-table_data_set, Columnname:-info

data format:

```
{
   "al_uri":"https://al/ma/np_6101",
   "parameters":[
      {
         "file_name":"QPR.AP6101_%Y%m%d",
         "input_format":"fixed",
         "output_format":"parquet",
         "delimiter":"None",
         "extension":".dat",
         "header":0,
         "footer":0,
         "date_pattern":"%Y%m%d%H%M%S",
         "type":"incremental"
      }
   ]
}
```

How to extract `QPR.AP6101_%Y%m%d` from the array. Tried below query, but not returning data.

```
select name,info ->> 'al_uri' as URL,info -> 'parameters' ->> 'file_name' as filename 
from table_data_set;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `->` operator also has a version where the right hand argument is an integer, that will select the corresponding array element.

So you want:

```
select name,
       info ->> 'al_uri' as URL,
       info -> 'parameters' -> 0 ->> 'file_name' as filename 
from table_data_set;
```

`info -> 'parameters' -> 0` picks the first array elements from `parameters`

A slightly shorter version is the `#>>` operator which accepts a *path* to an element:

```
input #>> '{parameters,0,file_name}' as file_name
```