# How do we extract json array elements in postgresql

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

Tablename:-table_data_set_attr, Columnname:-value. 
I have structured data and json data in the same column as below:

data format in 1st row:
https://al/mic/nap_6101

dataformat in 2nd row

```
[{'file_name': 'QPRACE2.SSTD.KRATOA.AP6101_%Y%m%d', 'input_format': 'fixed', 'output_format': 'parquet', 'delimiter': 'None', 'extension': '.dat', 'header': 0, 'footer': 0, 'date_pattern': '%Y%m%d%H%M%S', 'type': 'incremental'}]
```

How to extract the structured data from the first row(https://al/mic/nap_6101) and `QPRACE2.SSTD.KRATOA.AP6101_%Y%m%d` from the array. Tried below query, but not returning data.

```
select value -> 0 ->> 'file_name' as filename 
from table_data_set_attr;
```

Comment: It's the same solution as your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62014327

Comment: The data is coming in single quotes. I believe that is the problem. Is that correct.